# nginx auth_request error auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client

Tags: nginx, auth-request

I'm really new to nginx and am having some trouble with auth_request.

With the following conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php;
    server_name www.test.com;

    error_page 401 403 = @error401;

    location @error401 {
        return 302 http://login.test.com;
    }

    auth_request /auth;

    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://auth.test.com;

        proxy_pass_request_body off;

        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        if ($http_cookie ~* "sso_token=([^;]+)(?:;|$)") {
            set $token "$1";
        }
        proxy_set_header X-SSO-TOKEN $token;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

When accessing http://www.test.com I am getting a `500` http status code.

And in the error log

```
auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 172.16.8.23, server: www.test.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.test.com"
```

At the moment http://auth.test.com just returns a `401` if `X-SSO-TOKEN` is missing, and `200` if it's there. It doesn't return a `302`.

I think the `proxy_pass` itself is returning it's `302` to `auth_request` module, rather than following it and returning the last status code (if that makes sense?)

Looking at these docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html this should work, but I can't figure it out.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue!

This was a school boy error :(

I was running nginx in a VM, and only on my host machine had I added the /etc/hosts entries for the *.test.com domains. So the internal proxy_pass call were going to the real auth.test.com which was returning a 302. After adding the host entries in my VM, all worked fine.